# How to add Conditional CSS class based on Python If statement

Tags: python, jinja2, webapp2

How do you add a conditional CSS class based on a Python if statement in the following example to show the `has-success has-feedback` form element?

```
<div class="form-group {% if not error_username %} has-success has-feedback {% endif %}">
```

Comment: Does what you have not work?

Comment: It did not. I ended up running `{% if error_username %}` and then div class to run on if error, then `{% else %}` for div with no error and finally `{% endif %}` but it was a lot of code.

Comment: That works perfectly fine using jinja2 version 3

Answer (score 53):

Write if condition this way.

```
<div class="form-group {{'has-success has-feedback' if not error_username }}">
```

Comment: Just in case: the full form allows `else` as well. The manpage: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#if-expression